# generate unique and random list of string pairs python

Tags: python, random

I am trying to generate a list of pairs of random strings.

The size of the list should be an input.

I.e. for a list with size 4 I should get  ["AD", "DF", "AA", "JD"]

I am able to generate a single random number store it in a list and keep generating random numbers and checking if they were already generated and if not add them in the list until the number of pairs I need...

Is there any function that could return the list directly?

Comment: return it to where/what?  Not sure I catch your drift, sir.  `return` isn't enough?

Comment: possible duplicate of [random generation of unique combination from two column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14826378/random-generation-of-unique-combination-from-two-column)

Comment: @BartoszKP: I believe it is different because here I need unique values for each string on the output list...

Comment: In this one you have a unique solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300162/how-to-merge-two-elements-of-two-lists-in-python-at-random-and-ensure-resulting It REALLY wasn't very hard to find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
import string

def random_strings(n):
    strings = set()
    while len(strings) < n:
        strings.add(''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in xrange(2)))
    return list(strings)

print random_strings(4)
```

Comment: Of course, for performance, this assumes you want much fewer than 26*26 = 676 strings. If you want 674 or 675, it'd be better to generate all combinations and randomly choose from that.

Comment: Thanks Paul! Pleale correct me if I am wrong, but with this code I would not guarantee t

Comment: guarantee that the strings are unique...

Comment: Thanks! just used your code to generate a large list and then filter the unique ones.